# How can I change firefox's default screen size?

Tags: firefox

My monitor screen size is 1920 X 1080. But firefox shows 1520 X 760. How can I change to 1920 X 1080 size?

Comment: What does that even mean? Firefox doesn't have a "resolution". It only has a window size that occupies a certain amount of space within the display area.

Comment: Ohh sorry I changed it.

Comment: Where does it show 1520 X 760?

Comment: I checked it using measurelt On firefox extension.

Comment: Might want to verify what the extension says is true. I think I tried this extension once and it was unreliable.

Comment: It's true. I checked it with `$(window).width()` jquery code.

Comment: Maybe you have Firefox zoomed in? Or you have your monitor set to a different resolution?

Comment: You're correct. I didn't know before. My problem is solved.Thanks.